# Git workflow for sudden high priority task

Tags: git

I am working on a feature branch with a mixture of staged and unstaged changes. A high priority task comes in. What should I do?

It appears `git checkout` does not touch staged and unstaged changes. So should I:

```
git add -A
git commit -am "must stop working to fix bug!"
git checkout master
git checkout -b "bug_branch"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awesome thing about git, is it's ability to provide you with multiple ways to achieve a goal, letting you adapt git to your workflow, rather than adapting your own workflow to git.

There are multiple ways to do this, such as:

Stash your changes then switch to the bug branch, then apply the stash when you are done with your bug fix.

Commit your changes locally, switch to the bug branch fix the bug, then fixup your local commit history with a `git rebase -i`

Commit your current changes to a new local branch, switch to the bug branch, fix the bug, then merge your changes from the local temp branch back to your feature branch.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple options. It would be great for the next reader to have examples.

Answer (score 7):

You can temporarily commit your work to the stash using `git stash save`, fix the bug or do whatever high-priority task you need to do, then apply the stash back with `git stash apply` and continue working.

http://book.git-scm.com/4_stashing.html

Comment: A particular advantage of `git stash` is that it saves both the working tree and index, and restores both, which is useful if you care about the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do that, or instead of that `git commit`, you can do a `git stash` also :)  Then once you are done with the bug fix, you can return to your state via `git stash apply`

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/10/stashing-your-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

**git stash** is your friend. Assuming you are on your bug_fix branch

```
git stash save "must stop working to fix bug!"
git checkout master
.. do some stuff
git commit -am 'foo'
git checkout bug_fix
git stash pop
```

Note that "git stash pop" restores the stashed changes, which is what you want for the most time. If you want to apply the changes in the stash and keep them in the stash, use git stash apply. This is useful if you want to apply your stash to several branches:

```
git checkout branch1
git stash apply
git checkout branch2
git stash apply
git checkout branch3
git stash apply
```

etc